# Freemarker Template Attempt/Recover error is not logged in freemarker.runtime.attempt

Tags: java, freemarker

I have the following code:

```
<#attempt>
    <#include "brands/custom.ftl">
<#recover>
    <#include "brands/default.ftl">
</#attempt>
```

The idea was to have a custom template when it's available, or default when it's not. As far as I understood, all errors generated inside an attempt/recover block would be logged as: freemarker.runtime.attempt as per [this page](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_logging.html), but it seems that it doesn't, or it doesn't appear to be the case.

> Logs template exceptions thrown during template processing, but caught by attempt/recover directives. Enable DEBUG severity to see the exceptions.

For me it generates the following error:

```
freemarker.log.JDK14LoggerFactory$JDK14Logger error
SEVERE: Template processing error: "Error reading included file brands/custom.ftl"

Error reading included file brands/custom.ftl
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> include "brands/custom.ftl" [on line 5, column 9 in _header.ftl]
 in include "_header.ftl" [on line 2, column 1 in index.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Error reading included file brands/custom.ftl
at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:167)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:361)
at freemarker.core.AttemptBlock.accept(AttemptBlock.java:73)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1508)
at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:259)
at com.company.portal.http.Controller.processTemplate(Controller.java:586)
at com.company.portal.http.Controller.guardedService(Controller.java:354)
at com.company.portal.http.Controller.service(Controller.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionHandlerValve.invoke(RedisSessionHandlerValve.java:26)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template brands/custom.ftl not found.
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:580)
at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:1490)
at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:157)
... 41 more
```

How do I make it so that it doesn't generate a SEVERE error?

Comment: [Documentation says](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_attempt.html#ref.directive.attempt):  "Errors occurring during template execution are always logged, even if they occur inside an attempt block."

Comment: Please take a look at [this page](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_logging.html) - Eventhough all errors are always logged, attempt/recover errors are logged as freemarker.runtime.attempt and are supposed to be available when in debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#attempt`/`#recover` documentation says: "Errors occurring during template execution are always logged, even if they occur inside an attempt block." The exception captured by `#recover` are **also** logged under "[DEBUG] freemarker.runtime.attempt". That said, you can't use `#attempt`/`#recover` to do normal flow control. It's for disaster recovery, like when something goes down but you don't want to fail the whole page, just show some error indicator and go on. But you still want to alert the sysadmins or whoever gets the error logs.

As of what you want to achieve, there's no directive built in for this. However, in the 2.3.21 API (not yet out... GitHub 2.3 or 2.3-gae head), `Environment` has a `Template getTemplateForInclusion(String name, String encoding, boolean parse, boolean ignoreMissing)` method - note the last parameter. If this method returns with non-`null`, then you can proceed with `include(Template)`, otherwise you can try to get another template. You can implement a custom directive with `TemplateDirectiveModel` that does this.

BTW, are you sure this logic is justified? Can't just the application tell the template what's the name of the template to include? (I don't like if a logic depends on a file to be missing. What's if it's missing by accident, like even, because of a typo? Now the template won't fail and tell you, just falls back and include something else silently.)

Comment: You have a point there with the logic depending on a missing file. What I was trying to do was keep the logic on the front-end level. I will re-think the approach and see if I can achieve similar result in a different way.